# Remove #N/A in vlookup result

Tags: excel, vlookup

How do I modify this function so that the result will merely be a blank cell rather than having #N/A show up if B2 has nothing in that cell?

I *think* I might need something like an ISERROR check but I don't 100% know what I'm doing.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Index!A1:B12,2,FALSE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you only want to return a blank when B2 is blank you can use an additional IF function for that scenario specifically, i.e.

`=IF(B2="","",VLOOKUP(B2,Index!A1:B12,2,FALSE))`

or to return a blank with **any error** from the VLOOKUP (e.g. including if B2 is populated but that value isn't found by the VLOOKUP) you can use IFERROR function if you have **Excel 2007** or later, i.e.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Index!A1:B12,2,FALSE),"")`

in earlier versions you need to repeat the VLOOKUP, e.g.

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,Index!A1:B12,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(B2,Index!A1:B12,2,FALSE))`

Comment: That did it! I'm using Excel 2003 so that last line did the trick. Thank you :)

Comment: Yep, IFERROR is what I needed to. IF just wasn't cuttin' it!

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to change the colour of the cell in case of vlookup error then go for conditional formatting . To do this go the "CONDITIONAL FORMATTING" > "NEW RULE". In this choose the "Select the rule type" = "Format only cells that contains" . After this the window below changes , in which choose "Error" in the first drop-down .After this proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### New Answer 9/28/2022

Here a new approach considering the new Excel function: [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

```
=XLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5,"Not Found",0)
```

The third argument indicates the value to use in case of not found, you can replace it with `""` in case you want to leave the cell empty.

[image: sample excel file]

Check the following additional resources for more information about this new function:

1. [XLOOKUP vs VLOOKUP: Which Excel Function Is Better?](https://www.makeuseof.com/xlookup-vs-vlookup/#:%7E:text=XLOOKUP%20is%20much%20more%20flexible,any%20column%20in%20either%20direction.). It is more flexible than `VLOOKUP`, you can specify `lookup_array` and `lookup_result` ranges.
2. [Performance of XLOOKUP: How fast is the new XLOOKUP vs. VLOOKUP?](https://professor-excel.com/performance-of-xlookup-how-fast-is-the-new-xlookup-vs-vlookup/):it seems some concern about `XLOOKUP` performance. Something to watch.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid errors in any excel function, use the Error Handling functions that start with IS* in Excel. 
Embed your function with these error handing functions and avoid the undesirable text in your results. 
More info in [OfficeTricks Page](http://officetricks.com/remove-na-excel-error-vlookup/)